# How can I show a splash screen when my React Native application is in the background?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an Expo based React Native application. I would like this application to display a splash screen when looking at background applications, rather than the screen the user is actually on. This is something i've seen in other applications.

I want to do this because the app might be displaying personal information, and will later add the ability to unlock via biometrics or PIN code when the application returns to an active state.

When I use AppState to do this, however, it doesn't seem to work - I still see the screen the user was on. Some example code is below, but I have also tried using the event to change a "showSplaceScreen" useState() to toggle the splash screen on permanently as a test. In this case the splash screen only appears once the app returns to the foreground.

I suspect that the application is being "paused" before the screen can change. Can anybody advise of a good way to do this reliably?

```
export default function App() {
  const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState);
  const [appStateVisible, setAppStateVisible] = useState(appState.current);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', (nextAppState) => {
      appState.current = nextAppState;
      setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);


  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

  if (appStateVisible != 'active') {
    return <SplashScreen />;
  }
  
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.NavigatorinitialRouteName="Dashboard">
        <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={DashboardScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="FirstRun" component={FirstRunScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="OnboardingProgress" component={OnboardingProgressScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="OnboardingExplainer" component={OnboardingExplainerScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="OnboardingAuth" component={OnboardingAuthScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="OnboardingPasscode" component={OnboardingPasscodeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="OnboardingEmailVerification" component={OnboardingEmailVerification} />
        <Stack.Screen name="OnboardingClient" component={OnboardingClientScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```